# Second launch is slower than the first run- on Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory, particle-system

I build a 3D game in Unity, and I run it on an Android phone,
when I hit- build and run on Unity- the app works fast and smooth on mobile for its first time,
then when I exit the app on the phone (terminate it) and reopen it to launch the game for the second time- everything is a bit slower- especially the particles.
I don't understand why, I don't keep anything in memory.

What reason can an app be fast at the first time and slower (not smooth) at the second time?

Comment: Garbage-men are mysterious beasts of wonder...

Comment: Have you used the remote profiler?